# iPhone Gmail app push notifications not working

Tags: iphone, gmail, notifications, apns

Push notifications in Gmail app on my iPhone are not working properly anymore. I have the Primary only selected for my push notifications. For some reason I am getting notifications for the emails I don't care about in my primary inbox, and all of the email I actually care about in my primary inbox I am not getting notifications. Can I please get some ideas on how to fix this?

Are there any other good apps for getting push notifications for Gmail?

Comment: You can use BoxCar for example. I have the same issue with notifications, this is a Google problem.

Answer (score 1):

From inside the app, go to settings and turn off notifications, save, turn them back on, save. This seems to fix the problem until it happens again. It seems to happen about once a month, but that's sketchy memory reporting the frequency.